# htaccess not redirecting request to specific folders and files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to build a custom mvc framework in php and its folder structure is something like this in my localhost.

- Controllers(Dir)
- Models(Dir)
- Views(Dir)
- Lib(Dir)
- Config(Dir)
- Lang(Dir)
- Public
- .htaccess

In this .htaccess file I am redirecting all the request in the public folder and the code in this .htaccess file is as follows

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And the following is my public folder contents

- css(Dir)
- js(Dir)
- images(Dir)
- mod(Dir)
- index.php
- .htaccess

In this htaccess I am checking if the requested uri is not the folder or file in this folder then pass that request to index.php, which in turn does the url processing for controllers and actions etc. And its code is as follows

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %[REQUEST_FILENAME] !-f
RewriteCond %[REQUEST_FILENAME] !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [PT,L]
</IfModule>
```

Everything is working fine except when I try to use any css file,js, image or any php file in mod directory(I am calling those file via ajax) it still pass that request to index.php which again try to locate them as a controller etc.

So please can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and how can I solve this problem. I still don't fully understand Rewrite Rules and Conditions so its possible that I have done something wrong in my rules.

Thank you,
Anchal Bhargava